# Child controller executed before Parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

In my parent view I retrieve a json file with this code and I use ng-repeat in a child view to access it.

```
    $scope.services = Services.query();

factory('Services', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/services/:serviceId', {
    serviceId: '@_id'
  }, {});
```

Until here everything is fine.
The problems start when I want to access the child view directly, or when I refresh the page. I am still able to show the content of the json file in the view with ng-repeat. But I can't use the file in the child controller. I tried this code in the child to try to identify the problem

```
  if($scope.services){ // in both cases it's not null
  var s="";
  if($scope.selectedService)
  s="NO refresh an NO direct access";
  else
  s="refresh or direct access";

  console.log(s);
  console.log("data : " + $scope.services);
  console.log($scope.services.length);
  console.log($scope.services)
  }
```

And here is the output [image]
[image]
[image]

Maybe the child controller is executed before the parent controller ? how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is probably that the parent calls [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) which has delay, because it fetches the JSON with a asynchronous HTTP request.

During that delay the child controller will execute.

You can verify that by adding a console.log in the parent controller:

```
console.log("Starting Services.query()");
$scope.services = Services.query();
```

Then you will see that the parent controller executes before the child controller.

The solution for this is to change the logic in the child controller to not being dependant on that the `$scope.services` being available when the controller is created.

Comment: That's true, parent controller execute before child :/ is there any solution ?

Comment: I edited and added a suggested "solution", but the question is too broad to be answered here. Would recommend reading up some on AngularJS bindings and $scope.$watch.